# Can't npm install on a TFS2017 pipeline

Tags: tfs

I would like to create a build pipeline of my Angular application.
In this one I want to do 5 jobs:

1- import the sources

2- install npm

3- build the application with npm build

4- Create an archive

5- And publish it in a folder.

but the task hangs at the npm install.
Can you explain the error?

[image]

This is the debug.log

[image]

Comment: If you login to your build machine and run npm install is it work?

Comment: Cést bien cela le probleme, le systeme de connection ne marche pas, j'ai trouvé comme information qu'il fallait configuré le poxy. mais lequel celui de ma machine ou sur TFS ?

Comment: @Jeremiej Do you mean your build agent machine can not connect to npmrc?

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT
I am using the package.json file not the .npmrc

Comment: @Jeremie Could you explain "the connection system does not work"? If you set variable system.debug to True, are you able to get more log?

Comment: @Jeremie Can your build agent machine access the  https://registry.npmjs.org?

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT, yes a have more log, thank you for this option I did not know it.
I don't know why the report indicates that the command npm install succeeded, and yet the pipeline has been running for 20 minutes without ending.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220729/discussion-between-jeremie-and-cece-dong-msft).

Comment: @Jeremie The report indicated the build would run `npm install` task, it didn't mean the command npm install succeeded. Can the account running your build agent access the packages?